# How to automaticaly enter sudo's grace period upon login

Tags: linux-mint, sudo, gdm

Knowing that giving a user a sudo's grace period right from the point when he/she login might be a security issue, I still think it will be a beneficial trade-off between security and usability in my setup.

The question is: how to do that? As far as I know, the sudo doesn't provide CLI for it.

I might somehow divert the gdm's typed password to something like `sudo false`, but again: how to get hold of the provided by the user password in the plain text? Should I write a custom `pam` module for it?

Or maybe it is better to immerse into implementation details of the sudo and as a root directly manipulate the timestamp database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gross hack, not really tested:

- Add the following line to `/etc/pam.d/gdm`:

  ```
  # Update the sudo ticket; proceed whether this succeeds or fails
  session [success=ignore new_authtok_reqd=ignore] optional pam_exec.so seteuid /usr/local/sbin/update_sudo_ticket
  ```
- Content of `/usr/local/sbin/update_sudo_ticket`:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  DIR=/var/run/sudo/$PAM_USER
  if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then touch "$DIR"; else mkdir "$DIR"; fi
  ```

You must have the `tty_ticket` option turned off in `/etc/sudoers` (otherwise, it doesn't make sense anyway: a Gdm login wouldn't count for whatever you do in a virtual terminal in your X session).

I don't guarantee that this works. I don't guarantee that this doesn't introduce a glaring security hole. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Wouldn't running `sudo -v -u $PAM_USER` instead of the script have been a better solution?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Would you be running that as root or as the user who's logging in? If you run that as root, it updates root's sudo ticket, which is not useful. If you run it as the user who's logging in, it requires them entering the password again.

Answer (score 1):

Gilles had inspired me to the following, simpler solution. Make sure that executable file `/etc/mdm/PostLogin/Default` in Linux-Mint Mate (`/etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default` in Ubuntu) contains the following line:

```
touch /var/lib/sudo/$LOGNAME
```