# How to automatically enter sudo's grace period upon CLI login?

Tags: shell, sudo, pam, authorization

What I would like to do is be able to login and sudo commands immediately without entering a password again. It is very redundant to type my password twice in a row when I need to login and run a privileged command. I understand the security risk which requires us to reenter a password when we've been away for awhile but it seems like login should automatically set this session by default to prevent this but it doesn't for some reason.

I am aware of [these solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61974/how-to-automaticaly-enter-sudos-grace-period-upon-login) but they both rely on gdm and I appear to only have LightDM installed for starters. Furthermore, I don't login to a GUI interface and AFAIK the console doesn't use either of these to manage logins in the first place.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 in VMware if that matters. I do have a KDE installed but I don't usually load it unless I have a reason to.

The ideal solution would also work from SSH logins.

**Update**:

Based on Gilles' suggestions I now have this working setup:

```
~ tail -n1 /etc/pam.d/sshd
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /usr/local/sbin/update_sudo_ticket
```

and ([be sure](http://fabrizioregini.info/blog/2012/10/01/sudo-and-tty_tickets/) to use `sudo visudo` to edit sudoers)

```
~  sudo head -n12 /etc/sudoers|tail -n1
Defaults        !tty_tickets
```

and create a new script

```
~ cat /usr/local/sbin/update_sudo_ticket
#!/bin/sh
touch -c "/var/lib/sudo/$PAM_USER" 2>/dev/null
```

and make it executable ( `sudo chmod u=+rwx,g=+rx-w,o=-rwx /usr/local/sbin/update_sudo_ticket` ):

```
~  ls -la /usr/local/sbin/update_sudo_ticket
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 57 Sep 21 20:52 /usr/local/sbin/update_sudo_ticket
```

Comment: Why don't you just log in as `root` if you know that you want use privileged commands?

Comment: My root passwords are very long auto generated hash strings. I don't make my user account passwords as complex.

Also, at least two of my servers have multiple users in our team whom are able to log in and I don't want to give everyone the root account. Even though these are dev\testing servers they could potentially cause me hours and hours of work fixing something if they mess it up. I use the white list feature of sudo so that these users don't have completely unfettered access. If that is the only alternative then they'll just need to keep entering a second password.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`pam_exec`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html) to invoke an external command. Beware that `pam_exec` runs in an environment that is under the control of the user who calls the login service, so don't invoke it from `su`, only from services with a predictable environment such as `sshd` or `login`.

`sudo` has no option to update a user's time stamp, only to remove it. So you'll have to update the time stamp manually. If you aren't using the `tty_tickets` option (which is not very useful), all you need to do is update the timestamp on the directory.

```
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /usr/local/sbin/update_sudo_ticket
```

where `/usr/local/sbin/update_sudo_ticket` is something like

```
#!/bin/sh
touch -c "/var/lib/sudo/$PAM_USER" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Would i add that to /etc/pam.d/login and /etc/pam.d/sshd then? Just on the end I suppose.

Comment: @krowe Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Not quite working I'm afraid. See my update.

Comment: Found the problem. I had forgotten to update the sudoers file.

Comment: *all you need to do is update the timestamp on the directory* – How to find out this directory?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost `sudo -V | grep 'timestamp dir'`

Answer (score -2):

Edit your /etc/sudoers file with visudo and add this line:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Then make sure your user is part of group `wheel`:

```
usermod -a -G wheel USERNAME_HERE
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked for: they want to trigger the grace time, not forgo the password entirely (for every user in `wheel`)...

Comment: Yes, this isn't the same as what I was wanting. OTOH, if no one can give me solution which works the way I've asked for this is definitely a workable alternative. The wheel group had completely slipped my mind. It won't work for every server but on most it'd be fine.